# Adding watermark to document

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I add a watermark to one A4 page of text?
You know, the standard image-as-a-watermark.
I tried doing it in MS Word, the text ended up forming a blanket over the image. Photoshop CS5 was not a success for me either.

I eventually had to resort to printing the image first and then the text, but how can I avoid having to do this in future?

Comment: What's the final format you are wanting to have? Word? PDF? Jpg? Plain Text???

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing the whole thing in Word, try putting it in the header/footer. That should place it behind all of your text.

Alternatively, if you click the image and go to "Format" in the ribbon (I'm using Office 2010), click "Wrap Text" and then "Behind Text". That should do the trick regardless of where you insert the image.

Comment: to expand slightly, while editing the "format" of the image for placement, you may want to set the position to be based relative to "page." IIRC, word defaults to "column"

Answer (score 1):

In photoshop: open the image you want to use as a watermark, save as high-res transparent .png with about 10% opacity (adjust as neccessary, but this is a pretty good starting point). Open the file you want to watermark, File > Place > Select the png you saved, size as appropriate. You can also record an action that will place your watermark automatically and run it whenever you are done editing an image.